# How can I force a twig variable to resolve to a string?

Tags: php, json, twig, json-ld

I have a twig template that generates JSON-LD at the bottom of a blog page. Here is a section of the JSON metadata:

```
    {% set dateString %}
        "datePublished": "{{ post.post_date|date('c') }}",
    {% endset %}
    {{ post.settings.hide_publish_date ? '' : '{{ dateString }}' }},
```

The output when I view the source code of the webpage is this:

```
"DatePublished": "{{ dateString }}",
```

What I expected to see was something like this:

```
"DatePublished": "2017-03-15T10:59:56+00:00",
```

How can I ensure that my variable `dateString` resolves to the expected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the date value to output correctly by using the [twig replace filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html).

```
{% set dateString %}
    "datePublished": "{{ post.post_date|date('c') }}",
{% endset %}
{{ post.settings.hide_publish_date ? '' : '%dateOutput%'|replace({'%dateOutput%': dateString}) }}
```

The webpage now outputs the expected values to the JSON-LD:

```
"DatePublished": "2017-03-15T10:59:56+00:00",
```

Comment: `{% set dateString  = '"datePublished": "'~post.post_date|date('c')~'",' %}`

Comment: Twig between `set` and `endset` is not interpolated, just like `'` and `"` in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can use `template_from_string` function of twig:

> The `template_from_string` function is not available by default. You must add the Twig_Extension_StringLoader extension explicitly when creating your Twig environment:

You can find more details on http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/template_from_string.html